# Ruby Javascript and Assets

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, url, coffeescript, asset-pipeline

I am trying to add my first bit of javascript into my rails application and so to test it in my app/assets/javascripts/users.js.coffee I added the lines:

```
square = (x) -> x * x
alert square(10)
```

When i load up the app normally and travel to a page normally using url `localhost:3000`, my browser does not alert me *however* when I travel to the page with url `localhost:3000/?debug_assets=1` it does show the alert (100).

I feel as though I have not configured my rails application properly in my config file but that is just a guess.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Asuming you have these lines in you gem file.

```
gem 'rails', '3.1.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'coffee-rails', "~> 3.1.0"
```

You'll should have this line in your /app/views/layout.html.erb file

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
```

and this in your /app/assets/javascript/application.js file

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .
```

or

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require users
```

finally in the /app/assets/javascript/users.js.coffee

```
jQuery ->
    square = (x) -> x * x
    alert square(10)
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

There may be a bug in your javascript that is only coming up when all your javascript is dumped into a single file.  Have you looked in your javascript console for any errors?  It's possible these don't come up when you run in debug mode.